# Discord.js write data to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Heyo,
I need help here. I want to structure a JSON file. Down here I can explain it a little bit better:

I have a channelId and a serverName and I want to safe these in a config file with fs.
Here is how it would look now:

```
    {
  "server": "MyServer"
    }
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "channelId": "MyChannel",
    "info": [
      {
        "server": "MyServer"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
const server = "MyServer"
const channel = "MyChannel" //I want this to be at the top

  const template = {           //this must be edited i think
    server: "Cool Server",     
  }
   template.server = server;
  fs.writeFileSync("channels.json", JSON.stringify(template, null, 2));
```

With "server" I mean the server where the channel exists.
Thanks for helping me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can do this. Try this as an easy fix.

```
const server = "MyServer";
const channel = "MyChannel"; //You want this to be at the top

const template = [
  {
    channelId: "Your Channel",
    info: [
      {
        server: "Your Server",
      },
    ],
  },
];
template[0].channelId = channel;
template[0].info[0].server = server;
fs.writeFileSync("channels.json", JSON.stringify(template, null, 2));
```

Later on you can use a for loop or `map` function on the template array to add channels and servers dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, it's working ;) Do you have an idea how to add more than only one channel to the file?

Comment: It depends on how you store the information of servers and their corresponding channels. The basic idea is to store the information in an array. On a small scale, you can add the information manually or read it from a file. Only then you can `stringify` them into JSON.

Comment: okay, I'll take a look at it.